# JSF Ajax Call with JQuery Mobile

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsf, mobile

This issue has been troubling me to no end!!

I have seen the forum post [JSF f:ajax listener not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848203/jsf-fajax-listener-not-called) which describes my exact issue.

I am using JSF 2.0 and am using the Jquery mobile as an extension library.

I have actually copied the code exactly from the post, into my project (shown below).

I have the same managed bean set in session scope, printing out a line. I can see the bean successfully executing on the first input text *the one assigned with an ajax listener*

It doesn't however work for the button. In my use case, I want the button only to act as a bridge for calling the managed bean, so don't want the form to submit.

I am at a complete loss as to why the bean isn't executed?

I have no overriding JS classes either, and am using Jquery mobile only.

Is this a restriction on the Jquery framework? or more than likely an issue with my code?

S

```
<h:form id="f1">
<h:panelGroup id="switchSearchTexts">
    <h:inputText accesskey="s" alt="Search" id="searchBoxPeople" title="Search Plebeians" valueChangeListener="#{peopleBean.simplePersonQuery}" size="25" rendered="#{peopleBean.easySearch}">
        <f:ajax render="peopleDataTable" event="keyup" listener="#{contactsBean.morePressed}"
                immediate="true"/>
    </h:inputText>

    <h:inputText accesskey="s" alt="Search First Name" id="searchBoxFN" title="Search First Name" size="25" rendered="#{!peopleBean.easySearch}">
        <f:ajax render="moreButtonAsText" event="keyup" />
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>

<div id="expandBox">
    <h:inputText id="searchBoxLN" alt="Search Last Name" styleClass="hideToggle" title="Search Last Name" size="25" />
    <h:inputText id="searchBoxAddress" alt="Search Address" styleClass="hideToggle" title="Search Address" size="25" />
</div>

<h:commandButton type="button" styleClass="moreButtonAsText" id="moreButtonAsText" value="More">
    <f:ajax listener="#{contactsBeanFaces.morePressed}"/>
</h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

*** CORRECTION ****

---

my apologies, I was seriously trying everything! and posted the wrong iteration of code!
I have found a great note:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/ajax-jsf-joined which has been a huge help, however still no success. I am feeling jquery mobile is messing with the event?

I believe that there may also be a requirement for the button to be in a form?

Sorry abou the basic questions, however i am a Jdeveloper guy, who is kind of learning backwards.... the DOM and client java / html  side of things is almost unfairly hidden with this application. I am loving client side libraries and learning whole lot through this process.... but a strong requirement is that I can call server side logic!

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: you want to click the `moreButtonAsText` button on each keyup ?

Comment: my apologies, I was seriously trying everything! and posted the wrong iteration of code!

Comment: Oh sorry Daniel - no, I just want to be able to execute a bean (I use this for server side row set manipulation) is master detail relationship. I want to create an edit address screen that displays an employee's address in one form - only the selected address. To do this, I want to execute a managed bean on the server to select the chosen record for display/edit. I will use the user click to select the record and kick off this process.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved.

The issue is that the managed bean needs to be set up with the right signature event as an input param. Through lots of testing, I was trying to use the same class taking an AjaxBehaviorEvent. As in the same example on the previous forum.

when I declared an ActionListener event (compliant with the button jsf action), the bean is executed!

Stoked, and shows what fresh eyes can bring!

Thanks Daniel!

S